# Mybatis how to return only selected columns when set result map to Dto

Tags: spring, mybatis

I have some question about mybatis and resultMap specified Dto.

```
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.Date; 

@Data 
public class BasicBoardArticle {

private int articleIdx;

private int subBoardIdx;

private String title;

private int userIdx;

private String userNickName;

private String content;

private int good;

private int bad;

private Date createDate;

private Date updateDate;
}
```

I have above Dto and then select like below

```
<select id="selectAll" resultType="BasicBoardArticle" >
    SELECT
        articleIdx
        , bad
        , createDate
        , title
        , userNickName
    FROM BASICBOARDARTICLE
</select>
```

but when controller return the dto 'BasicBoardArticle', it would return all properties(such as subBoardIdx, updateDate, etc) as null which I even didn't select.
 is there any way to get rid of those properties from the returing Dto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do exactly what you are asking for in java.

The class `BasicBoardArticle` has the properties and they can't just disappear from it. Think of the code that uses this class. It can try to get say `updateDate`. And it is a valid thing to do as the class defines this property and java is strongly typed so you can't dynamically add/remove properties.

So you can either

1. alter the class (or create another class) to have only fields that you need
2. or change the serialization of the class to return only fields that you need (or as an option skip null fields)
3. or convert the instance of `BasicBoardArticle` that is returned to some other class that does not have these fields

### Separate mapping in mybatis

Create a separate class with only the fields that you need. Then create a separate `resultMap` for it (if you use `autoMapping=true` the only real difference is the target type you specify in `resultMap`).

Then you either create a separate query in mapper or include the fields conditionally based on some parameter value using `<if>`.

### Change serialized form

If `selectAll` is used only in presentation layer you can customize how the class is serialized. Either create custom serializer for it and use it in the controller for this particular endpoint (though there's no easy way to do that unless you use different request content types). Or configure jackson to not return null fields if you can afford that for this class.

### Convert to other type

If result of `selectAll` is used not only in view layer it may make sense to convert the returned `BasicBoardArticle` to some other type that only have fields that you need.

Answer (score 0):

IF I understood correctly you don't want subBoardIdx, updateDate in your DTO, upon your query

```
<select id="selectAll" resultType="BasicBoardArticle" >
SELECT
    articleIdx
    , bad
    , createDate
    , title
    , userNickName
FROM BASICBOARDARTICLE
</select>
```

But your DTO has these fields so that'll always return those, you could change this by mapping that to a Model Object that would not have these fields

something like this the fields on you want

```
public class BasicBoardArticleModel {

private int articleIdx;

private String title;

private String userNickName;

private int bad;

private Date createDate;

}
```

and you could map your desired fields from your DTO to this Data Model and use it